# How to add more CSS properties in this Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redirect

Can anyone tell me how to add or assign more properties to this given javascript.

```
$('#mydoom').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
});
```

You see the above script has only one css tag/property **visibility:hidden**, how can I add more properties...

Something like this **example**:

```
$('#mydoom').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden')
     ($(this).css('display') == 'none')
     ($(this).css('font-size') == '25px')
     ($(this).css('color') == 'red')
 {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
});
```

You see the above scripts holds many properties...so how can I do that, this is not working which I've shown you above as an example.

## I Updated the post to make its more clear:

Example here is my page: which has this script:

I created to help convey, how to make this script to work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mydoom').each(function () {
    if 
($(this).css('font-size') != '25px') // See if the font-size is **25** if not then redirect.
($(this).css('color') != 'red') // See if the color is **red** if not redirect .
($(this).css('position') != 'relative') // See if the position is **relative** if not redirect.
($(this).css('float') != 'left') // See if the float is **left** if not redirect.
{
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
});
})
//]]>
</script>
```

**I add the html and wrong css properties too to to check the redirection**

```
<style>
  #mydoom {position:absolute;}
  #mydoom {font-size:24px;}
  #mydoom {color:white;}
</style>

<div id="mydoom">
mydoom
  </div>
```

you see, i put position:**absolute** font-size:**24px** and color:**white** but the page is not redirect why ? as i already set in javascript to check its value if it does not match then redirect the page. so how to make the script to work.

i hope you got the point.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The css property is in the "IF" condition. You can chain those with logical operators.

Comment: @maniexx  i want a redirection, if the if satement check the several css properties assign to id #mydoom...then redirect the page...it work with single property but how to add to check multiple tags, like color, font-size, and many i set there...thanks

Comment: @RajeshSurry If you are checking for each and every property to be like that, concatenate each check with `&&`.

Comment: @RajeshSurry Moreover, there can be only one `#mydoom` because, it is an `id`.

Comment: @RajeshSurry Kindly tell if my understanding is right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  yes, there should be only one id #mydoom  i tested my page but the redirect not happened...here you see my another script. <style>
  #mydoom {display:none;}
  #mydoom {font-size:24px;}
</style>

<div id="mydoom">
mydoom
  </div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mydoom').each(function () {

if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' && $(this).css('display') == 'none' && $(this).css('font-size') != '25px' && $(this).css('color') == 'red') {
  document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
   }
});

})
//]]>
</script>

Comment: @RajeshSurry [edit] your post da...

Comment: @PraveenKumar i updated the post, check its updated section

Comment: @RajeshSurry Again wrong man... No `&&`. Check my answer or the other answers.

Comment: 1 sentence: **read the documentation**!

Answer (score 1):

That is not working because that's not valid javascript. What you need to do is add an && sign between each clause and correct the parathesis.

I suggest you read up on javascript, or programming syntax in general. Below is the code fixed.

```
$('#mydoom').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' && $(this).css('display') == 'none' && $(this).css('font-size') == '25px' && $(this).css('color') == 'red'){
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
});
```

Warning, untested, but it should work fine.

[Edit] Just wanted to add in, like the user below, that id's are unique, so you need to add a class instead if you want loop over a number of objects in the dom.

So you just add the attribute class to your elements, like this:

```
<div class="mydom"></div>
```

and then you just use .mydom as selector.

Comment: i have added this in my page but the redirect is not happened.    <style>
  #mydoom {display:none;}
  #mydoom {font-size:24px;}
</style>

<div id="mydoom">
mydoom
  </div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mydoom').each(function () {

if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' && $(this).css('display') == 'none' && $(this).css('font-size') != '25px' && $(this).css('color') == 'red') {
  document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
   }
});

})
//]]>
</script>  now what to do to make this redirection possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `if` statement. It should be like:

```
if (condition1 [&& or || condition2]) ...
```

So change your `if` to:

```
if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' && $(this).css('display') == 'none' && $(this).css('font-size') == '25px' && $(this).css('color') == 'red')
```

To make it clear:

```
if (
  $(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' &&  // See if the visibility is hidden.
  $(this).css('display') == 'none' &&       // See if the display is set to none.
  $(this).css('font-size') == '25px' &&     // See if the font-size is 25px.
  $(this).css('color') == 'red'             // See if the colour is red.
)                                           // And if everything above is right, then...
```

Moreover, there can be only one `#mydoom` because, it is an `id`.

**Update:**

Success and failure fiddles:

- [Fail](http://output.jsbin.com/toxiyaxati)
- [Success](http://jsbin.com/wohigetufi)

For some reason, the `$("#mydoom").css("color")` fails returning `undefined`.

#### **Snippets**

**Fail**

```js
$(function() {
  if (
    $("#mydoom").css('visibility') == 'hidden' && // See if the visibility is hidden.
    $("#mydoom").css('display') == 'none' && // See if the display is set to none.
    $("#mydoom").css('font-size') == '25px' && // See if the font-size is 25px.
    $("#mydoom").css('color') == 'red' // See if the colour is red.
  )
    $("body").append("Success");
  else
    $("body").append("Fail");
});
```

```css
#mydoom {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="mydoom">
  mydoom
</div>
```

**Success**

```js
$(function() {
  if (
    $("#mydoom").css('visibility') == 'hidden' && // See if the visibility is hidden.
    $("#mydoom").css('display') == 'none' && // See if the display is set to none.
    $("#mydoom").css('font-size') == '25px' // See if the font-size is 25px.
    // $("#mydoom").css('color') == 'red'          // See if the colour is red.
  )
    $("body").append("Success");
  else
    $("body").append("Fail");
});
```

```css
#mydoom {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="mydoom">
  mydoom
</div>
```

Comment: @RajeshSurry Stop commenting like this man. I already replied.

Comment: @RajeshSurry Again wrong man... So many `(` and only one `)` and no `&&`. See the above code correctly, at least copy and paste.

Comment: @RajeshSurry And finally it is supposed to be `location.href` or `window.location.href`.

Comment: @RajeshSurry Fiddle: [Fail](http://output.jsbin.com/toxiyaxati) and [Success](http://jsbin.com/wohigetufi). Something is preventing from getting the colour information.

Comment: your code is great working, but it also not working with padding:5px, i set padding:5px but it failed, check my fiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/v7x0yt02/15/   why it not working with padding and color property. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple properties in an object like this:

```
$(this).css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'none', 'font-size': '25px'})
```

Comment: Nopes. He's trying to check if each of the rule is that way. You are setting it, but the OP's interested in getting it.